# S3 presigned URL file upload failing with secured/https URL

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have two buckets, one private and one public. Private will have file with CannedAccessControlList.Private and public will have file with CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead. Apart from these they are all same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>



AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY,AWS_SECRET_KEY));
            generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(AWS_BUCKET_PRIVATE_NAME, path,HttpMethod.PUT);
            generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration); 
            generatePresignedUrlRequest.putCustomRequestHeader("x-amz-acl", CannedAccessControlList.Private.toString());
            generatePresignedUrlRequest.putCustomRequestHeader("content-type", fileType);
            url = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

I able to upload file to s3 in below scenarios. All generated URL are by default https.
1. private bucket with https
2. public bucket failed over https, replaced https to http it worked.

Problem why public bucket upload is failing with https. I can't work with http on production system as it have ssl installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things which I have learned.

1. S3 have two different styles of writing URL Path style and virtual host style. (You will have to be careful when your bucket looks like hostname)

Virtual Host Style

https://xyz.com.s3.amazonaws.com/myObjectKey

Path style

https://s3.amazonaws.com/xyz.com/myObjectKey

Ajax call to upload file fails in first case if you are on https, since SSL certificate is valid only for s3.amazonaws.com and if bucket name like hostname SSL check will fail and block ajax upload call.

Solution for this in Java

```
s3client.setS3ClientOptions(new S3ClientOptions().withPathStyleAccess(true));
```

2. I am still not able to figure out how S3client which region to pick for URL formation, but I found some time it is picking proper "s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com" and sometimes it picks "s3.amazonaws.com".

In later case you upload will again fail mentioning CORS issues, If you presigned URL is s3.amazonaws.com and even if you have enabled CORS in your buckets its not gonna pick "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". So you need make to make sure you are giving proper region name using below code.

```
s3client.setEndpoint("s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com");//or whatever region you bucket is in.
```

Reference :http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/amazon-s3-gotcha-using-virtual-host.html

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by creating a folder inside my bucket and 
generated pre-signed url for `"my-bucket/folder"` instead of `"my-bucket"`.